# Refused to display '....' in an iframe because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny' in Lightning Communities

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, iframe

I have a Visualforce page embedded inside an iframe with in a Lightning Component placed in the Lightning community. When I logged in as authenticated user, I am able to see the component. But when I try to view the component as Guest Profile user, i am getting the below error

"Refused to display '....' in an iframe because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'"

And, 
I gave the visual force page access to the Guest User Profile and in community also i made the settings for Click jack protection as recommended.

And, 
Unchecked the Click Jack protection settings for visual force pages in Session settings.

[image]